# Logging Out of Stack Overflow Does Not Log Me Out of Meta

Tags: discussion, security

I was wondering how come after logging out of Stack Overflow, I am still logged in on Meta. From Meta, I can still access Stack Overflow without ever having to log in again.

Is there a security flaw or is it a design on purpose?

Answer (score 6):

Meta Stack Overflow is a separate site from Stack Overflow - you log into them each on their own. So your logged in status on one does not affect the other.

This is not the case with the newer StackExchange websites, where logging into the parent site also logs you in on the associated meta site.

Comment: @ Grant Palin, I disagree with your first statement. I am using the same credential on both sites and I only need to log in to Stack Overflow to access Meta Stack Overflow. So the log in status on one site *does* affect the other.